# Canonical example to understand Gibbs Sampling

Tags: references, gibbs

I'm been trying to understand Gibbs sampling.

What I'm looking for is a paper or other reference which uses a simple canonical example and uses that to illustrate Gibbs sampling.

Sadly I've not found one that does that.

Would appreciate any such reference or other advice.

Thanks.

Comment: You should probably state which papers (etc) you've looked at and in what ways they were inadequate

Comment: You may want to wait to see if you get better answers; you should feel free to move the tick if you do.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Some suggestions:

Casella, G. & George, E.I. (1992),
["Explaining the Gibbs Sampler,"](http://biostat.jhsph.edu/~mmccall/articles/casella_1992.pdf)
*The American Statistician*,  **46**(3) (Aug.), pp. 167-174

chatty with very simple examples, but to me didn't quite motivate as well as:

Gelfand, A.E., & Smith, A.F.M. (1990),
["Sampling-Based Approaches to Calculating Marginal Densities,"](http://www.stat.tamu.edu/~fliang/Gelfand2.pdf)
*Journal of the American Statistical Association*, **85**, 398-409.

which has a slightly more theoretical approach. The immediately following paper in the same issue of the journal has some good real data examples.

Answer (score 2):

Andrieu, C. et al. (2003)
["An Introduction to MCMC for Machine Learning"](http://www.cs.princeton.edu/courses/archive/spr06/cos598C/papers/AndrieuFreitasDoucetJordan2003.pdf)

which covers Gibbs sampling in section 3.4, though I'd encourage you to read from the beginning. I liked it because it puts the subject well in perspective and was quite accessible to me.